# Is there a time zone for Australia inside the Regional setting for the site collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, regional-settings, timezone

I am working for a client in Australia, and i am trying to set the time zone to be equal to Australia, but i could not find any:-

[image]

any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Australia does not have *a time zone*. It has *five*.

[image]

Even on your screenshot one can clearly see 3 Australian time zones:

[image]

Likely, you will need UTC+10 Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney since most of Australia lives there.

Comment: thanks .it worked